# integral inequality over rectangles implies same inequality over all measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Consider the Lebesgue measure and the Lebesgue-measurable sets $\mathfrak M$ over $\mathbb R^N$.

Let $f\colon \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$ be measurable and a.e. bounded. In order to show that $f\geq 0$ a.e., it is sufficient to prove that 
$$ \forall A \in \mathfrak M,\;\int_A f \geq 0$$

Supposes that the analogous inequality holds for rectangles, that is $\int_R f \geq 0$ for every rectangle $R$. Given $U$ open subset of $\mathbb R^N$, it can be written as a countable disjoint union of (dyadic) cubes so that $U=\bigsqcup_n Q_n$ and so
$$\int_U f=\sum_n \int_{Q_n} f \geq 0$$

Now, given $A \in \mathfrak M$, suppose that it is bounded. By Outer regularity of Lebesgue measure
$$ \mathscr L(A)=\inf\{\mathscr L(U): A \subset U,\, U\,\mbox{open}\}$$
so that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists and open set $U$ containing $A$ and such that $\mathscr L(U)<\mathscr L (A)+\varepsilon$. Then
$$0 \leq \int_U f=\int_{U\setminus A}f + \int_A f < \varepsilon \|f\|_{L^\infty}+\int_A f$$
and taking $\varepsilon \to 0$ one gets the desider inequality. Otherwise, if $A$ is not bounded, then $A=\bigcup_n(A \cap B_n)$ with $B_n=B(0,n)$. Then $A \cap B_n \in \mathfrak M$ so that $\int_{A \cap B_n} f \geq 0$ for every $n$. Finally
$$\int_A f= \lim_n \int_{A \cap B_n} f \geq 0$$

**Question:** is my reasoning correct?